# Узнать список таблиц доступных пользователю

Tags: sql, oracle

Как из-под пользователя узнать список таблиц, к которым он имеет доступ?

У пользователя нет административных прав, поэтому он не может обращаться к системным таблицам `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под "иметь доступ" ? Таблицы о которых можно посмотреть информацию? Таблицы из которых можно сделать select? Таблицы в которые можно делать update ? таблицы из которых можно делать delet ? Таблицы которые есть в схеме пользователя?

Comment: @Viktorov В данном случае, надо узнать перечень таблиц, который он сам создавал. Например, как делает графический PLSQL? Он ведь, как-то выводит список таблиц, к которым имеет доступ пользователь.

Comment: Все еще не понятно. Можно создавать таблицы в своей схеме, а можно в чужой схеме. Сходу не знаю ни 1го способа, как узнать какие таблицы в чужой схеме создавал пользователь. А если только свои собственные, то посмотрите первую редакцию ответа @0xdb

Comment: @Viktorov Хорошо, а как тогда узнать, что он имеет какие-либо права (даже если только чтение) в своих схемах или чужих.

Comment: @Viktorov Повторюсь, как-то ведь plsql developer это делает.

Comment: У вас есть некоторое недопонимание.  "своих схемах" - тут мн.ч. неуместно, один пользователь БД это всегда только одна схема. "что он имеет какие-либо права" - достаточно, что ему дадут самое минимальное право - `read`, и он увидит таблицу из "чужой" схемы в представлении `all_tables`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так можно посмотреть весь список таблиц, к которым у пользователя есть доступ:

```sql
select owner||'.'||table_name
from all_tables;
```

Comment: Это просто список таблиц в схеме пользователя. При этом пользователь может иметь права работать с таблицами других пользователей

Comment: @Viktorov А да, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Спасибо, вот этих комманд было достаточно: 
`SELECT  table_name FROM user_tables;`
`SELECT  table_name FROM dba_tables;`

Comment: Посмею не согласится. 1) `user_tables` это все таблицы пользователя и он **всегда имеет к ним полный доступ**. Кроме того, `all_tables` содержит таблицы, к которым он также **имеет доступ**, хотя и не всегда полный.  2) Цитирую: "_У пользователя нет административных прав_" . Но без определённых  административных прав вы представление `dba_tables` даже  не увидите и не сможете им воспользоваться.

Comment: @0xdb я так вас и понял :)

Comment: Да, права делать запрос на all_tables вам даны через public автоматом. Префикс dba_ значит - database administrator, и на все представления с ним  нужны административные права.